# Select IDs where every column of same ID meets condition

Tags: mysql

I want to select IDs where every column of same ID meets condition but I can't figure out the query to get that result.
The table looks like this:

```
text  | id
----------
text1 | 1
text2 | 1
text3 | 1
text1 | 2
text3 | 2
text2 | 3
```

Excepted result `SELECT id FROM table WHERE text IN ("text1", "text2")`

```
id
--
1
```

Comment: can you add sample data set related to above example

Comment: @MaheshMadushanka What do you mean? There's a sample table with columns text and id.

Comment: i want to get your requirement in clearly if using the above table if you can provide the expected result set that will be great

Comment: @MaheshMadushanka Well there's a result for example query with condition

Comment: thanks initial it was not clear to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT id
FROM `table` AS t1
INNER JOIN `table` AS t2 USING (id)
WHERE t1.text = "text1" AND t2.text = "text2"
```

Comment: Thank you, but isn't there a simpler way than joining the table for example 10 times to check for 10 different values? Also if the table is really large it will probably be very performance demanding right?

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT DISTINCT id FROM  table WHERE text IN ("text1", "text2")`

Answer (score 0):

join same table again

```
    SELECT t.id from 
(SELECT id FROM table WHERE text IN ("text1")) t 
INNER JOIN  
(SELECT id FROM table WHERE text IN ( "text2")) 
on tt t.id=tt.id;
```